# Getting rid of console logs in redux wrapper with Next.js

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, next.js, redux-thunk

Hey guys I just downloaded some source file from internet which uses redux thunk with Next.js in order to see how things work and then after running it with `npm run dev` the project runs successfully but then in console I keep getting this logs:

```
1. WrappedApp.getInitialProps wrapper got the store with state {
  loginAndSignupReducer: [],
  getCategoryReducer: { loading: false, err: false, data: [] },
  MyStoryReducer: { loading: false, err: false, data: [] },
  reportStoryReducer: { loading: false, err: false, data: [] },
  getAllDetails: []
}
3. WrappedApp.getInitialProps has store state {
  loginAndSignupReducer: [],
  getCategoryReducer: { loading: false, err: false, data: [] },
  MyStoryReducer: { loading: false, err: false, data: [] },
  reportStoryReducer: { loading: false, err: false, data: [] },
  getAllDetails: []
}
4. WrappedApp.render created new store with initialState {
  loginAndSignupReducer: [],
  getCategoryReducer: { loading: false, err: false, data: [] },
  MyStoryReducer: { loading: false, err: false, data: [] },
  reportStoryReducer: { loading: false, err: false, data: [] },
  getAllDetails: []
}
```

These things get rendered first of all and so because of this. I also see them in page source as objects

I have shared an image below please refer to it, I rendered my id in <p> tag but then here I am seeing it as object.

[image: I rendered my ID in tag but here i am seeing it as object]

Does anyone from where to get rid of them permanently?

Answer (score 4):

This is most likely because you copy the code sample from the [docs](https://github.com/kirill-konshin/next-redux-wrapper#usage) which sets `debug` to `true` when you create a wrapper:

```js
export const wrapper = createWrapper<State>(makeStore, {debug: true});
```

Remove the `debug` property or set it to `false` to fix the issue

```js
export const wrapper = createWrapper<State>(makeStore);
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 61159443/getting-rid-of-console-logs-in-redux-wrapper-with-next-js]

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons for this that I can think of, either the Debug Property is set to false during the wrapper creation. To Fix that, do this

```js
// From This
const wrapper = createWrapper<RootState>(initializeStore, { debug: true })

// To This
const wrapper = createWrapper<RootState>(initializeStore, { debug: false })

// Or Rather
const wrapper = createWrapper<RootState>(initializeStore)
```

Or you might have some middleware like "logger" in your State. So if that's the case get rid of any middleware you don't need. Logger can be replaced with `redux-devtools-extension`